# TypeError: update_purchases() missing 1 required positional argument: 'code'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, kivy

I'm new in python and I'm currently developing a POS system, this is the code for the cart of the customer. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

The Code:

```
    def update_purchases(self, code):
        pcode = self.ids.code_inp.text
        products_container = self.ids.products

        target_code = "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE product_code LIKE '%s'"
        code = [code]
        self.mycursor.execute(target_code, code)
        self.mydb.commit()

        if target_code == None:
            pass
        else:
            details = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height=30,
                                pos_hint={'top': 1})
            products_container.add_widget(details)

            code = Label(text=pcode, size_hint_x=.2, color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            name = Label(text=target_code['product_name'], size_hint_x=.3,
                         color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            qty = Label(text='1', size_hint_x=.1, color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            disc = Label(text='0.00', size_hint_x=.1, color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            price = Label(text=target_code['product_price'], size_hint_x=.1,
                          color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            total = Label(text='0.00', size_hint_x=.2,
                          color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            details.add_widget(code)
            details.add_widget(name)
            details.add_widget(qty)
            details.add_widget(disc)
            details.add_widget(price)
            details.add_widget(total)
```

The error:

```
   File "c:\Users\acer\Downloads\pos\operator\operate.kv", line 113, in <module>
     on_text_validate: root.update_purchases()
 TypeError: update_purchases() missing 1 required positional argument: 'code'
```

Comment: I see update_purchases is part of a class. Do you create an object of that class and then call update_purchases over that object? It looks like you are trying to call that method as if it was static, but it is not.

Comment: I'm trying to insert mysql on to my code, at first the error is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'code' referenced before assignment` then I typed 'code' to the arguments of update_purchases then that error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your `code = [code]` assignment is doing, what is [code]? This might be why you're getting the first error message. The second error message is because you've put code as an argument in your class but when you call `root.update_purchases()` you don't pass any value, you would need to pass something like `root.update_purchases(code.text)`